# how to run script based off current value in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity0" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="calculate(this.form);">
<input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity1" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="calculate(this.form);">
<div id="tix_total_quantity_div">0</div>

$(function(){
var testThis = document.getElementById("tix_total_quantity_div").value;
  $('[id*="tix_quantity"]').on('change', function(){
    $value = Math.max(0, Number(testThis.value) - 1);
    $('div[class*="guest-"]').hide().slice(0, $value).show();
  });

});

$('#Ar-ttClassesContainer').insertAfter('#Ar-attendContainer');

  });
```

The #tix_total_quantity_div automatically updates adding the values of tix_quantity0 and tix_quantity1. The script that controls that is hard coded into the page, I cannot edit it directly. if you put a 1 in tix_quantity0 and a 2 in tix_quantity1 then tix_total_quantity_div will automaticlly update to 3

I am trying to get this script to run based on the value of #tix_total_quantity_div so that if you update one of the inputs that has an ID that contains "tix_quantity" and the tix_total_quantity_div updates the number of .guest- divs that will show will be based on the current number for #tix_total_quantity_div

I think I am stuck on this line:
$value = Math.max(0, Number(testThis.value) - 1);
If I us this.value then it works based off of the value entered into one of the tix_quantity boxes but how do i make this work based off of the current value for tix_total_quantity_div?

Comment: Using jquery `$('#tix_total_quantity_div').html()`

Comment: And also look into parseInt() - helps when dealing with numbers in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing: var testThis = 
    document.getElementById("tix_total_quantity_div").value;

and changing

```
$value = Math.max(0, Number(testThis.value) - 1);
```

to this instead:

```
$value = parseInt($('#tix_total_quantity_div').text()-1);
```